# ArrayFormula + simple if statement on Google Forms

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I am building a worksheet that takes form-submitted data and runs a few calculations. I am having trouble autopopulating cells with simple if statements. I am wondering about how to use ArrayFormula with a statement like:

`=IF(J2<I2+1,1,0)`

Or, even more complicated, an IF statement and a VLOOKUP:

`=IF(H2+K2=2,VLOOKUP(F2,'Event Info'!A2:D7,4,False),"Message")`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These formulae may work as you want.  The LEN(A2:A) section checks your column A and will only output if there is a timestamp value from the Form :

`=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(A2:A),IF(J2:J<I2:I+1,1,0),))`

`=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(A2:A),IF(H2:H+K2:K=2,VLOOKUP(F2:F,'Event Info'!A2:D7,4,0),"Message"),))`

Comment: Worked great. Thanks!